# Meteor: how to paginate simple-todos demo?

Tags: javascript, meteor, pagination

I am looking at Meteor pagination today.

I am interested in this repo:

https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages

The initial code shown looks simple:

```
this.Pages = new Meteor.Pagination("collection-name");
```

and:

```
<body>
    {{> collection-name}}
</body>
<template name="collection-name">
    {{> pages}}
    {{> pagesNav}}  <!--Bottom navigation-->
</template>
```

I want to paginate this demo:

https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos

The code I see there simplifies to this:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
    return Tasks.find({})})}


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Meteor.subscribe("tasks");
  // ...
}
```

and:

```
<body>
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>
    {{text}}
  </li>
</template>
```

Perhaps my brain is a bit slow today.
It is not obvious to me how to paginate the above code.

How do I use 
github.com/alethes/meteor-pages
to paginate the above code from simple-todos?

Comment: After getting the tasks in minimongo, filter criteria, sort criteria should be applied before fetching the appropriate page data. If the number of records is too large, the default meteor mechanism via minimongo does not perform well. Mini-mongo is best for small collections. For large collections, use server Meteor methods with the same criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've used meteor-pages, but you should be able to just do replace `Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");` with `this.Tasks = new Meteor.Pagination("tasks");` - common code between client and server.

Basically meteor pages just creates a wrapper around a mongo collection and applies search and filter criteria.

If you're familiar with coffeescript make sure to check out their `/examples` directory in the repo.

Also, the settings https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages#settings will help explain some of the defaults like items per page etc.